# Configured MySQL replication but its not working

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.5, high-availability

I have configured MySQL master and slave replication setup on 5.5.x.
*But for some reason data is not getting replicated properly.* What might be the reason?

**At Master:**

/etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
log-bin=/var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin.log
server-id=1
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
sync_binlog=1
binlog-do-db=cmdb
binlog-do-db=nagios
```

mysql> show master status;

```
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| File             | Position | Binlog_Do_DB | Binlog_Ignore_DB |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
| mysql-bin.000005 |   168019 | cmdb,nagios  |                  |
+------------------+----------+--------------+------------------+
```

**At Slave:**

/etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
server-id=2
log-bin=/var/lib/mysql/mysql-bin.log
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
sync_binlog=1
report-host=10.10.0.22
replicate-do-db=cmdb
replicate-do-db=nagios
```

mysql>  show slave status\G;

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: 10.10.0.21
                  Master_User: replicator
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000005
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 198123
               Relay_Log_File: CentOS62-relay-bin.000012
                Relay_Log_Pos: 198269
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000005
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB: cmdb,nagios
          Replicate_Ignore_DB:
           Replicate_Do_Table:
       Replicate_Ignore_Table:
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error:
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 198123
              Relay_Log_Space: 198574
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File:
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File:
           Master_SSL_CA_Path:
              Master_SSL_Cert:
            Master_SSL_Cipher:
               Master_SSL_Key:
        Seconds_Behind_Master: 0
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error:
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error:
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
             Master_Server_Id: 1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Do you have other databases on the master besides cmdb and nagios ?

Comment: Yes there are few other databases in the master table.

Answer (score 2):

What concerns me here is the use of both `replicate-do-db` on the Slave and `binlog-do-db` on the Master at the same time.

There is no need to use both. I would remove `binlog-do-db` from the Master. I would also look over any queries with fully qualified table names. Why ?

If you replicate any SQL use fully qualified table names (dbname.tblname) and you use replicate-do-db, MySQL Replication gets confused if you execute `USE dbname`.

[Percona explained this in conjunction with `binlog-do-db` and `replicate-do-db` back in May 2009](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/05/14/why-mysqls-binlog-do-db-option-is-dangerous/).

[Percona also suggested reading the replication filtering rules thoroughly](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-rules.html).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I tried removing the binlog-do-db from the master & replication is happening. But I see a strange behavior. In the same table some of the columns are getting replicated but few of the columns are not getting replicated. What might be the reason??