# MySQL Master-Slave Replication Cross Database

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.5, mysql-5, mysql-5.1

I am setting up Replication for cross Database as i have set 2 variables in Slave' s my.cnf as replicate-do-db=database_name and 
Replicate-wild-do-table=database_name.% ,But i am not able to get cross Database updates from master to slave . Please Help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: This might help: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?26,171776,205870#msg-205870

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I addressed something like back on June 14, 2012 : [Configured MySQL replication but its not working](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19236/configured-mysql-replication-but-its-not-working/19281#19281)

The basic problem may be the queries you are using

If you have a query that looks like this

```
INSERT INTO db1.tb SELECT * FROM db2.tb;
```

You could be potentially blocking queries of this nature

Queries like this:

```
USE db1
INSERT INTO tb SELECT * FROM db2.tb;
```

should work if you have `replicate-do-db=db1` and `Replicate-wild-do-table=db.%`

To be sure, [check out the replication filtering rules](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-rules.html) to make sure your queries are allowing your current settings to work on the Slave.

According to the replication filtering rules

> To make it easier to determine what effect an option set will have, it
> is recommended that you avoid mixing “do” and “ignore” options, or
> wildcard and nonwildcard options. An example of the latter that may
> have unintended effects is the use of --replicate-do-db and
> --replicate-wild-do-table together, where --replicate-wild-do-table uses a pattern for the database name that matches the name given for
> --replicate-do-db. Suppose a replication slave is started with --replicate-do-db=dbx --replicate-wild-do-table=db%.t1. Then, suppose that on the master, you issue the statement CREATE DATABASE dbx.
> Although you might expect it, this statement is not replicated because
> it does not reference a table named t1.

Perhaps you need to get rid of one of those rules on the Slave and restart mysql on the Slave.

Comment: what i am trying to say is when i insert value to db1.table from another database using simple query as use db2 ;insert into db1.table values (''); the values are not being inserted in db1.table on slave

Comment: Updated my answer...

Comment: You mean to say if i will use both variables as replicate-do-db and replicate-wild-do-table then MySQL will ignore the insertion/updation of data as ignoring on the basis Database Level

Comment: According the documentation : `An example of the latter that may have unintended effects is the use of --replicate-do-db and --replicate-wild-do-table together, where --replicate-wild-do-table uses a pattern for the database name that matches the name given for --replicate-do-db.`. One filtering is interfering with the other.