# MySQL Slave Relay Logging but not logging Binary Log

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.5, logs, wamp

I have a master slave setup both mysql 5.5, the setup is fine except that the slave won't Binary log to the standard mysql-binlog only to the relay logs. I fear this may be due to my lack of understanding on the matter but my ultimate goal is to setup another slave feeding off the current slave to then point the two together for a master-master relationship.

My problem is that although on the slave I can insert a record and the master replication position (on the slave) will change, it will not change as a result of slave activity on the same database. Will the slave not dump activity into both logs? If i point the secondary slave to relay logs what are my options down the line?

Hope that makes sense.

my my.ini setup on the slave is as such, a unique server id and hostname are also set:

```
binlog-do-db=our_database  
binlog-ignore-db=mysql  
binlog-ignore-db=test  
replicate-do-db=our_database
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot one thing

```
binlog-do-db=our_database  
binlog-ignore-db=mysql  
binlog-ignore-db=test  
replicate-do-db=our_database  
log-slave-updates
```

The option [**log-slave-updates**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_log_slave_updates) takes SQL that was read from relay logs and records them in the Slave Binary Logs when the SQL is completed.

Please be very careful. You should never use binlog-do-db and binlog-ignore-db simultaneously. I wrote about this back on Jun 14, 2012 ( [Configured MySQL replication but its not working](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19236/configured-mysql-replication-but-its-not-working/19281#19281) ) which points to [an old Percona article on binlog-do-db being dangerous](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/05/14/why-mysqls-binlog-do-db-option-is-dangerous/).

## SUGGESTION

Of the things you are using, you only need these lines

```
replicate-do-db=our_database  
log-slave-updates
```

You really don't need `binlog-do-db=our_database` once you have log-slave-updates working properly.

Comment: You were exactly right, as soon as that flag went in everything started going. I've taken your advice and cleaned up the ini file also, thanks again.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA If we don't need another slave to feed off this slave, we can switch off log-bin and log-slave-updates on the slave, correct?