# Mysql replication from existing slave to new slave

Tags: replication, mysql-5.5

I'm hoping you experts can help advise me, I've got this topology:

Live DB(Master) ----> Backup Server (Master and slave) ----> Test DB

**Backup server** is a slave of **Live DB**, and **Test DB** is a slave of **Backup server**

The replication from Live to backup server works as expected, the replication from backup to test is where I'm a little confused, if I create a test DB on backup, I can see it replicated to Test DB, but if I do the same on Live DB, it doesn't filter down to Test DB (but does to Backup).

Another thing I notice is that the binlog sizes on Backup are very small, only 150 Bytes, whereas they are close to 100M on Live, (binlog sizes set the same on live and backup)

Maybe this is by design?
Maybe it's not possible to chain slaves together?

I goal of Test DB was (once working) to replicated from our Hosted Datacenter to our internal office, then use the internal slave to update our Dev / QA / Training DBs here (reducing bandwidth usage).

Here are what the related settings are on the backup server:
(`/etc/mysql/my.cnf`)

```
log_bin                 = /srv/mysql-binlogs/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days        = 7
max_binlog_size         = 100M
binlog_cache_size       = 16M
binlog-format           = MIXED
```

Specs:

- `mysql 5.5`
- `Debian Squeeze`

Thanks, Your advice would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I missed one very important option:

log_slave_updates

Now the binlogs are growing!

ref: [MySQL Slave Relay Logging but not logging Binary Log](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29828/mysql-slave-relay-logging-but-not-logging-binary-log)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_log_slave_updates

Answer (score 0):

so you  are  creating  database on backup  server and it's replicating  on TestDB,but  if you  are  creating   on live server it's not  replicating  on backup server.

In the above case  check for    **replicate-do-db** or  **replicate-ignore-db** variable on **backup server** under my.cnf file.

Comment: Anything that happens on live gets correctly replicated to backup, but doesn't filter down to testdb, but anything I add to backup (only as a test), correctly replicates down to test.


those values (replicate-do-db and replicate-ignore-db are commented out on all servers) I want everything replicated.

Comment: if it helps, the only difference on the servers are the locations of the binlogs, on live it's in the default /var/lib/mysql directory, on backup it's on /srv/mysql-binlogs. (Test binlogs are in /var/lib/mysql)