# MySQL replication slave of slave not receiving updates

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.6

I have 4 servers: A, B, C and D.

A and B are in a master-master setup.

C is a slave to B and D is a slave to C.

Changes on A or B get to all nodes other than D. I need them to get to D

Changes on C get to D but obviously they don't go to A or B which is fine.

After some reading I found that I needed the log-slave-updates option set on C, this way C would log the changes replicated to it and then D could read those and make the same updates.

I have set the option to on and D is waiting for it's master to send events but changes from A or B are still not getting to D.

Comment: Please run `SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'server_id';` on all servers and tells us what server's server_id is.

Comment: Servers A, B, C and D have server-ids of 1, 2, 3 and 4

Comment: Is log-slave-updates configured on A, B and C ?

Comment: No it's only on C

Comment: Do I need it on A and B? If so does that require a restart before it will work?

Comment: Yes restart of mysqld is required because log-slave-updates is a global variable but is not dynamic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [log-slave-updates](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_log_slave_updates) on server C, only updates written directly on B will go to server D.

Server A and Server B require [log-slave-updates](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_log_slave_updates), otherwise, none of their updates will reach C. In general, any Master that is also a Slave must have [log-slave-updates](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/replication-options-binary-log.html#sysvar_log_slave_updates) in order to relay binlog events from distant servers.

I have discussed this before

- [MySQL Slave Relay Logging but not logging Binary Log](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29828/mysql-slave-relay-logging-but-not-logging-binary-log/29833#29833)
- [Multi-master + slaves replication in MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60391/multi-master-slaves-replication-in-mysql/60434#60434)

Restarting mysqld is required on servers A and B for the setting to take effect

Let me explain further

## Your Setup

- A is Slave of B (log-slave-updates off)
- B is Slave of A (log-slave-updates off)
- C is Slave of B (log-slave-updates on)
- D is Slave of C
- A, B, and C are Masters

You run `INSERT INTO tblname` on Server A what happens ?

Since B is Slave of A

- B's IO Thread reads A's binary logs
- B's IO Thread gets `INSERT INTO tblname`
- B's IO Thread records it in its relay logs
- B's SQL thread reads relay logs
- B's SQL thread gets `INSERT INTO tblname`
- B's SQL thread executes `INSERT INTO tblname`it
- Since B does not have log-slave-updates defined, B does not record `INSERT INTO tblname` into its binary logs. C's IO Thread never sees `INSERT INTO tblname` coming from server A.

You run `INSERT INTO tblname` on Server B what happens ?

Since A and C Slaves of B and D is a Slave of C

- A's IO Thread reads B's binary logs
- A's IO Thread gets `INSERT INTO tblname`
- A's IO Thread records it in its relay logs
- A's SQL thread reads relay logs
- A's SQL thread gets `INSERT INTO tblname`
- A's SQL thread executes `INSERT INTO tblname`it
- C's IO Thread reads B's binary logs
- C's IO Thread gets `INSERT INTO tblname`
- C's IO Thread records it in its relay logs
- C's SQL thread reads relay logs
- C's SQL thread gets `INSERT INTO tblname`
- C's SQL thread executes `INSERT INTO tblname`it
- Since C has log-slave-updates enabled, C records `INSERT INTO tblname` in its binary logs
- D's IO Thread reads C's binary logs
- D's IO Thread gets `INSERT INTO tblname`
- D's IO Thread records it in its relay logs
- D's SQL thread reads relay logs
- D's SQL thread gets `INSERT INTO tblname`
- D's SQL thread executes `INSERT INTO tblname`it

Based on this description, if you had any slaves coming from A, those slaves would never see `INSERT INTO tblname` coming from B.

Therefore, you need log-slave-updates on A and B as well as C.

Comment: The strange thing is they do reach C. I am testing by creating a new DB on A. The new DB appears on B and C but not D

Comment: Thanks, I have marked as answer even though I am waiting for the restart to know for sure.